# In Windows 10 where do I find actual resolution video sent by graphic card?

Tags: windows-10, video, graphics-card, resolution

In `Display Settings` I can see `Display resolution` drop down. I think, the recommended  value in `Display resolution` is the resolution of the monitor, but the graphic card may be sending video in lower resolution (according to it's max capacity) and monitor upscales it.

How to find the current output resolution at which video card is sending the output to display (In Windows 10)?

Comment: From Display Settings go to Advanced Display Settings. There you should have "Active signal resolution".

Comment: @User552853 That solves what I was looking for. Could you please write it as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on Desktop, go to `Display Settings` and then search for the `Advanced Display Settings` option. There you should have `Active signal resolution`.